# Associations without foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, associations

I'm trying to associate two entity types in EF4, there is no foreign key available.

Is there any manual tweaks I can do to so when I load an instance of order I get something like:

```
order.orderID = 455
order.date = 2012-08-12
order.OrderItems = <List>OrderItem // OrderItem being the other entity I want to map on         order
```

I guess I'll have to do this manually when I Select() an order and set it's OrderItems property since no FKs are avail.

Am I on the right track ?

**EDIT:

I was able to create an association between orders and orderitems and here's a Select() method I have for an order:

```
    public Order Select(long orderID)
    {
        using (var ctx = new BillingSystemEntities())
        {
            var res = from n in ctx.Orders
                      where n.OrderID == orderID
                      select n;
                 if (res.Count() == 0)
                    return null;
                else
                    return  res.First();
         }
    }
```

According to SQL Profiler, EF is not doing any JOIN on OrderItem table. I guess I need to load them into the OrderItems navigation property myself ?

Comment: If you're not using foreign keys, how do you associate the `OrderItem` to the `Order`?

Comment: You can tell EF that a column is a foreign key even if the database isn't configured as such.

Comment: cadrell0 is right. I DO have columns shared by both tables (orderID) so applications can link rows of both. It is just not configured as such in the DB.

Comment: cadrell0, how would I do that exactly though ? I tried creating an association, with no luck.

Comment: @Francis post what you have and I'll let you know if I see anything wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include the `OrderItems` in your query:

```
public Order Select(long orderID)
{
    using (var ctx = new BillingSystemEntities())
    {
        var res = from n in ctx.Orders.Include("OrderItems")
                  where n.OrderID == orderID
                  select n;
        return res.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Also `FirstOrDefault` is more appropriate here than your `Count()...First()` construct because it hits the database only once while `Count()` and `First()` will issue a separate query each.

You can write it even more compact with:

```
public Order Select(long orderID)
{
    using (var ctx = new BillingSystemEntities())
    {
        return ctx.Orders.Include("OrderItems")
            .FirstOrDefault(n => n.OrderID == orderID);
    }
}
```